# Datasource says not binding to IList...but I am aren't I

Tags: c#, telerik

I am getting:

```
Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource
```

which is straight forward. You need to be binding to a collection such as List instead of a single item...only I think I am binding to a List so what am I not understanding?

My Collection object is a singleton as such:

```
public class CalendarEvents
{
    private static CalendarEvents _calendareventshandle;

    internal List<CalendarEvent> ABCD_CalendarEvents { get; set; }

    //seal constructor
    private CalendarEvents() 
    {
        this.ABCD_CalendarEvents = new List<CalendarEvent>();
    }

    internal static CalendarEvents CalendarEventsHandle
    {
        get 
        {
            if(_calendareventshandle == null)
            {
                _calendareventshandle = new CalendarEvents();
            }

            return _calendareventshandle;
        }

    }        
}
```

My handle assignment:

```
CalendarEvents EventsCal = CalendarEvents.CalendarEventsHandle;
```

populating collection:

```
EventsCal.ABCD_CalendarEvents.Add(new CalendarEvent(...)); 
//40 records as I would expect for this scenario
```

and binding lines are:

```
radsched_InstCalendar.DataSource = EventsCal.ABCD_CalendarEvents;
```

What am I missing or doing wrong??

Thank You

---

Full Error minus stack

Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below

Comment: What is type is "radsched_InstCalender"?

Comment: Telerik radscheduler...http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/scheduler.aspx

Comment: Ok, have never tried it. But maybe it has something to do with the list beeing internal?

Comment: It it looks like you might need an `IListSource` != `IList`, a Telerik thing by the looks of it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm not following you. Where / how do you implement your suggestion...further is that some tidbit you've picked up or did I miss it in the docs?

Comment: I just read the error message... How accurate did you post it? And don't break them in half.

Comment: @HenkHolterman posted full error.

Comment: Starting to look like a Telerik bug but do replace `internal` with `public` to be sure. And verify it itsn't `null` at the moment of binding.

Comment: FWIW I just moved from singleton to multiple instantiations and same error...also changing the internal protection levels to public made no difference.